# What is wrong with my selection sort program using strings?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use an array with 5 words and arrange them in alpha order. I am kind of confused so if someone can explain to me what goes on and how to fix the code that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

Public Class Form1

```
Dim List() As String = {"bravo", "charlie", "zulu", "alpha", "whiskey"}
Dim swap, value As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim sw As String
Dim j, sp, x As Integer
Dim temp(0) As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = Nothing

    For i = 0 To List.Length - 1
        sw = List(i)
        sp = i
        For x = sp To List.Length - 2

        Next
        If sw > List(x) Then
            temp(0) = List(x)
            List(x) = sw
            sw = temp(0)
        End If
    Next
    For j = 0 To List.Length - 1
        Label1.Text &= List(j) & ", "
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Are you just wanting to sort the `List` itself ? If so just call `.Sort` on the list...

Comment: @Codexer - It sounds like homework.

Comment: @Enigmativity Not necessarily homework. But, the quarter ends tomorrow and I can't figure this out in class.

Comment: @Codexer The List() array needs to be sorted using selection sort. I have a button that puts everything in order in to a Label. Well, that is what I would like it to do :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your major problem with your code is the use of the `sw` variable. The problem is that when you do the assignment `sw = temp(0)` you are changing the reference that `sw` points to, but not the original `List(i)` that you assigned `sw` from in the first place. You're effectively updating a temporary variable and not the original list.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
For i = 0 To List.Length - 1
    For x = i To List.Length - 1
        If List(i) > List(x) Then
            Dim temp = List(x)
            List(x) = List(i)
            List(i) = temp
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I have also eliminated all of your class-level variables except for `List`. They were all unnecessary. The only one that you needed to keep was `temp` (as a `String` not a `String()`) and I put in in the `Button1_Click` method.

When I run this code on your original list I get this out:

```
alpha, bravo, charlie, whiskey, zulu
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your inner loop (`For x = sp To List.Length - 2`) is empty.
2. The inner loop end condition is incorrect. Why is it looping to `List.Length - 2`?
3. No need to use an array to store a temp string. `Dim temp As String` is enough.

Comment: What can I do to the inner loop? I'm kind of confused on this.

Comment: You may want to put statements in there so it will actually do some work. Also, read about [how selection sort works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Comment: Is my if statement in the correct area and will it work for selection sort?

Comment: sw = smallword in alpha order and sp = smallposition in the array

Comment: Yes you need a if statement after the inner loop for selection sort. And no it is not currently working because you are comparing with `List(x)` and it is always the second last item on the list.